Mapbox-gl-draw setting the drawing color of different polygons
I want to be able to have my own custom buttons that call the «start draw polygon» function from mapbox-gl-draw. The idea is to pass what type of polygon it is (custom definition), so that I in the «create polygon» section can set the right color for the polygons.
Example: custom-button-1 lets you draw a red polygon of type «operation area» and custom-button-2 a blue one of type/name «lifecycle tree area». I have created the two buttons, and I do engage the «polygon draw mode» when clicking on my buttons, but they both end up being red which is the default/fallback color in the styles.
Here is a shortened version of mye Mapbox Draw initializer file:

import MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';

export function initializeDrawTools(map) {
  const draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    userProperties: true,
    controls: {
      line_string: true,
      trash: true,
      polygon: true,
      point: true,
    },
    styles: [

// Set the fill and stroke style for the polygon
{
  id: 'gl-draw-polygon-fill',
  type: 'fill',
  filter: ['all', ['==', '$type', 'Polygon'], ['!=', 'mode', 'static']],
  paint: {
    'fill-color': [
      'case',
      ['==', ['get', 'user_draw_type'], 'operation-area'], '#00ff00', // Green
      ['==', ['get', 'user_draw_type'], 'lifecycle-tree-area'], '#0000ff', // Blue
      '#ff0000', // Red (default color)
    ],
    'fill-opacity': 0.3,
  },
},
]
});
}


Here is my function that the custom buttons calls:
export function activateDrawMode (map, draw, category, type) {
  if(category === 'polygon') {
    draw.changeMode('draw_polygon');
    map.on('draw.create', (e) => {
      console.log('e: ', e)
      feature = e.features[0];
      feature.properties.user_draw_type = type; // type === operation-area
      draw.add(feature);
    });
  }
}

In the console.log(‘e:’, e) I can see that the right property is being set, but the color of the polygon is still wrong… My only quess is that the property is being set after the style has already been decided so that it dosent know the features properties? If that makes sense.
Is there any other way of setting the drawing color of a polygon?
If I add it as hardcoded geojson like this, it works, but I want the user to be able to draw its own polygons:
  map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('polygon', {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
          'user_draw_type': 'operation-area' // Set the property here
        },
        'geometry': {
          'type': 'Polygon',
          'coordinates': [
            [
              [
                7.981685543413164,
                59.20133952768455
              ],
              [
                7.979057210222379,
                59.1885800447414
              ],
              [
                8.006263825512974,
                59.18468278810954
              ],
              [
                8.007310245455415,
                59.20867131238393
              ],
              [
                7.976252600208284,
                59.21691495637782
              ],
              [
                7.981685543413164,
                59.20133952768455
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    });

    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'polygon',
      'type': 'fill',
      'source': 'polygon',
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
        'fill-color': [
          'case',
          ['==', ['get', 'user_draw_type'], 'operation-area'], '#00ff00', // Green
          ['==', ['get', 'user_draw_type'], 'lifecycle-tree-area'], '#0000ff', // Blue
          '#ff0000', // Red (default color)
        ],
        'fill-opacity': 0.3,
      }
    });
  });


Welcome to StackOverflow, hope you will find new knowledge here. You can help us answering your question, by adding a minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet with the [< >] button in the editor. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.
